# Marathon problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A marathon runner starts running a distance of 40 km at 9:00. Due to the fatigue factor, their speed is proportional (with the proportionality coefficient k) to their distance to the finish. At 10:30 the runner passes the 20 km mark. At what time will the runner finish?

It seems that under the stated assumptions the runner will never finish the distance, which is somewhat counterintuitive. Is that still the correct answer?

Comment: Exponential decay ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay ) is a common process in many areas of science, and indeed it has the property that you never reach 0. So maybe you just need to adapt your intuition a bit :)

Comment: Yes. Every 90 minutes he gets halfway closer to the finish line. Since his speed is proportional to the remaining distance, all distances are in a sense equivalent to him; no matter how close he gets, the remainder of the race is just as hard as the entire original race.

Comment: You could adjust the factor k so that he arrives at 40km-10cm, so he still reaches the end wth his nose first.

Comment: Since a regulation marathon distance is actually $42.195$ km, maybe you can use that as the speed determiner and see when he passes $40$ km. :-)